# UPDATE or SET from a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database of information that should only be used one time. To grab the information to be exported into a `.CSV` file for use. I would use the following query, we also have the column `USED` which should be set to `YES` after the data has been exported (so it not re-used).

```
SELECT TOP(40000) 
    ms.website AS Website, 
    ms.company AS COMPANY, 
    ms.address AS [ADDRESS], 
    ms.city AS CITY, 
    ms.state AS [STATE], 
    ms.zip AS ZIP, 
    ms.phone AS PHONE
FROM
    [QUETABLE] as ms
WHERE  
    DEAD != 'YES' AND USED != 'YES';
```

And then I figured I would use this query to update the column "USED" so that if the same query was run again, only new information would be exported:

```
UPDATE TOP(40000) QUETABLE 
SET USED = 'YES' 
WHERE USED = 'NULL' AND DEAD != 'YES';
```

However, while a lot of the data was the same, for some reason, not all 40,0000 columns were matching, meaning un-used data would be marked as used (and vice versa), the USED column is set to NULL before its used (not IS NULL, but written "null').

How could I run the top query, but at the same time also set USED to "YES" so the information is identical? So, in broken SQL it would be like:

```
SELECT TOP(40000) 
       ms.website AS Website, 
       ms.company   AS COMPANY, 
       ms.address   AS [ADDRESS], 
       ms.city      AS CITY, 
       ms.state     AS [STATE], 
       ms.zip       AS ZIP, 
       ms.phone     AS PHONE
FROM   [QUETABLE] as ms
WHERE  DEAD != 'YES' AND USED != 'YES' THEN SET USED = 'YES';
```

But of course, that wouldn't work, I'm not sure how to accomplish this!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using `TOP` with no `ORDER BY`.  This returns an arbitrary set of rows.  There is no reason to think that the rows returned on two different runs *of the same query* would return the same rows, much less an `UPDATE` and a `SELECT`.

I would suggest that you use the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and do the work in the opposite order:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( . . . );  -- fill in the columns

UPDATE TOP(40000) QUETABLE
    SET USED = 'YES' 
    OUTPUT inserted.* INTO @t;
    WHERE USED = 'NULL' AND DEAD <> 'YES'
```

Now you can "export" the ones that were just set to `DONE`.